# My wifi router is supposed to support DFS channels -- but persists in not using them

Tags: wireless-networking

I've got the wifi router provided by my ISP: RAC2V1K. The filing with the FCC indicates that this router is certified for DFS. But on the other hand, it does not let me select a DFS channel and the router is never using a DFS channel (despite these channels being indicated as not in use by a wifi analyzer). Well, this could be, because of these channels are always in use by radar or because of the router does in fact not support DFS. Which is it? I did not find anything in the log regarding DFS.

The channel selection is set to Auto and it selects either channel 48 or 36 -- both are only 20Mhz wide. I set the bandwidth to 20/40/80Mhz.

Distance to the closest airport is 30mils -- 20mil (estimated) as the crow flies.

Comment: Are the channels it _does_ select otherwise free or are they busy? My understanding of DFS is that it's a requirement for the frequency to be selected, well, _dynamically_ so that the AP could itself move to a different one on detection.

Comment: The channel it does select (auto) is free (48) -- but it is only 20Mhz wide.